# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'd_data' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, to save a post in the database. (it´s a blog post with a video file). The "same" code works to sabe a post with an image, but in this one, I´m having problems with this error.

```
<?php
ob_start();
require '../blog.php';
use MYSITENAME\DB;

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data   =   $_POST['hoje'];
    $titulo =   $_POST['titulo'];
    $resumo =   $_POST['resumo'];
    $texto  =   $_POST['texto'];
    $videos =   $_FILES['videos'];
    $trimimg=   str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($_FILES["videos"]["name"]));



    DB\query(
        'INSERT INTO documentarios(d_data, d_titulo, d_resumo, d_texto, d_video) VALUES (:hoje, :titulo, :resumo, :texto, :videos)',
        array('hoje' => $data, 'titulo' => $titulo, 'resumo' => $resumo, 'texto' => $texto, 'videos' => $trimimg),
        $conn);

    mysql_close($conn);



    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["videos"]["tmp_name"], "videos/" . $trimimg);

    header("Location: admin2.php");
    exit();
}

else {
  echo "<b>Erro: pasta n&atilde;o permitida.</b>";
}
```

?>

the query function is:

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? $stmt : false;
}
```

And the form code:

```
<form name="inserird" id="inserird" method="POST" action="testecon.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input name="hoje" type="hidden" id="hoje" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" />
Titulo:<br />

<input name="titulo" type="text" id="titulo" size="40" /><br />
Resumo:<br />

<textarea name="resumo" id="resumo" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea><br />
Texto:<br />

<textarea name="texto" id="texto" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea><br />
Vídeo:<br />

  <input name="videos" type="file" id="videos" size="45" />
<br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar" /><br /><br />
```

Any help will be apreciated.
P.S.: sorry for the bad english.

Comment: You need to alter the table set `NULL` `No` to `NULL` Yes so that the table allows null values while doing the insertion.

Comment: I have tried this. When I run the test, it give me the same message, now in the second field of the table.

Comment: You need to do it for all the columns which you may have a null value while inserting other than the auto_increment primary key.

Comment: But all the columns are receiving input, and aren't expected to be null...

Comment: They are supposed to have values, check if you are getting the post values before doing the insert.

Comment: Nope. All the values returned the "Undefined index" error.

Comment: So check the form if its `method='POST'` and the field names are set properly as you are using in the code `$_POST['hoje'];` must have the html input with the name as `hoje`

Comment: Form code is ok. I will add the form code in the question.

Comment: Interesting could you check `print_r($_POST)` on the top of PHP code after you submit the form with data. Since your form looks good.

Comment: a blank array, and all the undefined index errors in sequence.

Comment: Do you have any javascript validation in place? This could effect what is being submitted, as your form looks ok above. - Another question - are you properly closing your `<form>` with `</form>` to ensure nothing lower on the page effects it too?

Comment: form is closed, and no validation. Weird.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file redirecting `testecon.php` or touching it at all?

Comment: No, don´t have it. This is strange.

Comment: Last thing i can think of, is `../blog.php` touching the `$_POST` variable at all?

Comment: No. it make the db connection and call the file with the functions - that don´t touch the $_POST variable